# What sort of disk scheduling algorithms are used in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, scheduling, disk

While it is possible to change the disk scheduling algorithm in Linux (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Disk_scheduling_algorithms), I am unable to find which disk scheduling algorithms are used in Microsoft Windows, or even how to change it. Might someone know more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "round robin technique". For more in depth knowledge [Here is a link](https://www.quora.com/Which-type-of-scheduling-algorithm-is-used-by-windows-10#:%7E:text=Windows%20uses%20a%20round%2Drobin,not%20interfer%20with%20foreground%20processes.). To know more about filesystems check out
[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disk-scheduling-algorithms/). And you cannot swap out the windows disk scheduling algorithm. There is a reason Linux is said to customizable mate.

Comment: Thank you! Though is that link about CPU or disk scheduling? Or both? It seems to be about CPU scheduling?

Comment: My bad, extremely sorry. I read the chain a few days ago for a brief period. It turns out the the answer at top ( first one) is about the disk scheduling and the next answer is of CPU scheduling. Do keep in mind that these results may be inaccurate a Windows is not open-source. If you really want to do something with these scheduling algorithms, just stick with linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and that answer also matches with https://www.quora.com/Which-disk-scheduling-algorithm-is-used-in-Windows 

However, these answers feel really strange, as round-robin does not seem to be listed as a standard algorithm for disk scheduling anywhere

Comment: @cs_student_273 Yes, as I said windows is not open-source. Thus, many really do not know what technique they use and how it works. So probably the reason behind it not being popular and showing up in lists.